How to replicate Makefile's wildcard and patsubst in Justfile?
When compiling C code, you need to convert every .c to a .o. Unfortunately, gcc doesn't have that ability. So you need to employ a make file that does it.
The code below is a simple example of using Makefile's wildcard and patsubst functions to do it.
The wildcard is easy, it's just globbing (src/*.c). The patsubst is the harder part for me. It replaces every string that it got from the wildcard to look like this ('obj/*.o').
After that, it runs gcc per each individual string that it got out. I've been looking through the docs of justhttps://just.systems/man/en/chapter_1.html, but I couldn't get it working.
# Define source directory
SRC_DIR := src

# Define object directory
OBJ_DIR := obj

# Define source files using wildcard function
SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.c)

# Define object files using patsubst function
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC_FILES))

# Compiler
CC := gcc

# Compiler flags
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Iinclude

# Target executable
TARGET := my_program

# Default rule to build the executable
$(TARGET): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

# Rule to compile source files into object files
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# Clean rule
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o $(TARGET)


Per its docs, "just is a command runner, not a build system".  Its syntax is inspired by make, but if your objective is to build software then make is designed for that and just explicitly isn't.

@gulpr alrighty...  Is there a one-liner that can do it? This doesn't work: gcc -c src/*.c -o obj/

The conclusion is wrong.

@gulpr. Which conclusion are you talking about?

@Al-BaraaEl-Hag, I also found that sentence irritating, not to mention easy to misunderstand.  I nearly edited it out, as it's barely germane anyway.  It's not a question of how "smart" gcc or any other compiler is.  Gcc doesn't need such a feature, because it doesn't have to work in a vacuum.  Indeed, consider why you even want such a feature.  You could build multiple source files directly to an executable.  The primary reason not to do so is to leverage make to reduce unnecessary recompilation.

@JohnBollinger. I've edited that part out. And yes, that does make sense.

Are you using Make or Just? If Just, why?

@HolyBlackCat I'm currently using Make. But I wanted to see if I should move over to Just. Their github page says: "just has a ton of useful features, and many improvements over make". I'm assuming that meant that it can do everything that Make does and more

Honestly, this doesn't sound like a good idea. I never heard of it. Manually writing makefiles is one thing (seems to be unpopular those days, but I still consider it to be viable), but learning some obscure dialect of it instead? That explicitly says it's not a build system? If you don't like Make, I'd learn something popular, like CMake or Meson.

@HolyBlackCat looking through the docs, I like Meson. I'll start using that instead, thanks!

As I already commented, just is not targeted at software building.  make is.  I'm sure that just does have some great improvements over make in service to its intended purpose of being a command runner.  It also avoids (again, per docs) a lot make features.  Moving from make to just seems ill advised to me.  It's like trading in my front-loader for the great new tow truck that has a control panel reminiscent of a front-loader's.  No doubt it's a superb tow truck, but it's not the right tool for the jobs that a front loader does.

@Al-BaraaEl-Hag I would suggest Cmake

I'm not sure why you feel a need to move at all when you've already got a working build system, but inasmuch as you do, Meson seems indeed a better alternative than just.  There are others.  All have their strengths and weaknesses.

I haven't gotten the full makefile made, but here is the code for the wildcard and patsubst:
# Define source directory
SRC_DIR := 'src'

# Define object directory
OBJ_DIR := 'obj'

# Define source files using wildcard
SRC_FILES := `echo src/*.c`

# Define object files
OBJ_FILES := replace_regex(SRC_FILES, SRC_DIR / '([^/]+)\.c(\s|$)', OBJ_DIR / '${1}.o$2')    

run:
    @echo {{SRC_FILES}}
    @echo {{OBJ_FILES}}

